# expr command not working in shell

Tags: shell

Following is the code that I tried -

```
nisarg@nisarg-ThinkPad-T61:~$ export a=1
nisarg@nisarg-ThinkPad-T61:~$ export b=2
nisarg@nisarg-ThinkPad-T61:~$ echo $a
1
nisarg@nisarg-ThinkPad-T61:~$ echo $b
2
nisarg@nisarg-ThinkPad-T61:~$ echo 'expr $a + $b'
expr $a + $b
```

I even made sure there are spaces around `+` as they are the cause of most errors.

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single quotes prevent `$a` and `$b` from being expanded, as well as `expr` from being called; you may be confusing single quotes with backquotes, which are the older syntax for command substitution. Use double quotes and `$( ... )`:

```
echo "$(expr $a + $b)"
```

The above code is equivalent to

```
expr $a + $b
```

so you only need the command substitution if you need to capture the output to assign to a variable or to embed the result in a longer string. Also, `expr` is unnecessary for arithmetic in a POSIX-compatible shell (i.e., almost any shell you are likely to be using). You can use an arithmetic expression `$(( ... ))` instead.

```
echo "$(( $a + $b ))"
```

Comment: OR `echo $((a+b))` also

Comment: Right; inside an arithmetic expression, any string literal is assumed to be a variable to expand, so the dollar sign is optional for simple parameter expansions.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=9
y=7
z=`expr $x + $y`
echo $z
```

Write the expression with spaces and surrounded with back-ticks (``).